# External Omnet++ Project as Feature

Tags: omnet++

I have two Omnet++ projects A and B. A currently needs B. Is it possible to declare B as a feature of A somehow, so I can turn it on and off? I want to have the separate projects as B can be reused in other projects. I added a feature using a new .oppfeatures file in A and I added corresponding ifdef statements in the C++ code. Currently I struggle with the ned file:

```
import namespaceB.B;
network Network
{
parameters:
[...]
bool bDisabled = default(false);
submodules:
[...]
b: B if !bDisabled;
}
```

How can I conditionally import the ned file of B? If I use a wildcard for importing Omnet complains about "no such module type" in the submodule declaration. Is my idea to have an external project as feature possible at all? Any other idea how I can accomplish this (maybe a git submodule or something)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow the pattern what INET is using with regards to the TCP implementations. INET has it's own TCP module (in the TCP_INET feature) and also two alternative implementation defined by the TCP_lwIP and TCP_NSC features. Take a look at the src/makefrags file to check the wizardry how to add compiler and linker flags based on the enablement of a particular feature. e.g.:

```
WITH_TCP_LWIP := $(shell (cd .. && ./bin/inet_featuretool -q isenabled TCP_lwIP && echo enabled) )
ifeq ($(WITH_TCP_LWIP), enabled)
  INCLUDE_PATH += -Iinet/transportlayer/tcp_lwip/lwip/include -Iinet/transportlayer/tcp_lwip/lwip/include/ipv4 -Iinet/transportlayer/tcp_lw
endif
```

This code checks whether the TCP_lwIP feature is enabled and adds the necessary include paths. You can add also linker flags if you have to link with the external project. (you can add compiler and linker flags also in the oppfeatures file if you don't need anything complicated )

Now, how to deal with the optional NED types? Also take a look at how the TCP module is defined in the StandardHost:

```
tcp: <default(firstAvailable("Tcp", "TcpLwip", "TcpNsc"))> like ITcp
```

As the given module is optional, you always have to have "something" that could be used instead of it. At least a dummy module. Now the there is an `ITcp` interface module (that is always present) and all the different TCP implementations "implement" it. What you see here is that `tcp` is a module which looks like the `ITcp` module and during the build up, the actual implementation will be either `Tcp`, `TcpLwip` or `TcpNsc` in this particular order. Whichever is present actually in the ned type tree. By disabling a feature, we actually remove the given ned type from the ned path too (the feature excludes the given NED package that contains the implememtation).

from the OMNeT++ API (NED functions):

*string firstAvailable(...)*

*Accepts any number of strings, interprets them as NED type names (qualified or unqualified), and returns the first one that exists and its C++ implementation class is also available. Throws an error if none of the types are available.*

This NED function was specifically invented and added to OMNeT++ for these purposes (to scan for the presence of a given NED type)